# Any sensible way to use Hudson with TFS workspaces?

Tags: tfs, hudson

I've been playing with Hudson and got the TFS source control integration running.  Problem is: it only allows you to specify a single folder as the source root.  We've got a lot of projects that share resources (including standard shared libraries).  If I could hard-link a folder like I could in source safe this wouldn't be an issue.  I can think of good solutions for other source control systems as well, but sadly I need to work with TFS, and I can't reorganize the folder structure.  Declaring things to be built from root would just be too slow.

Anyone any good ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Can you check out from command line? Than just do the checkout yourself, as one of the build steps.

Comment: This might actually be a goer.  Of course, I'd probably end up writing a plugin for it... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TFS, but I took a quick look at Hudson's TFS plugin and it looks analagous to all the other VCS plugins.

Unless I'm missing something, you should be better off setting up multiple Hudson jobs, each with a different TFS source folder, to build each of your projects; you can use inter-job dependencies to control things like rebuilding dependent projects when a shared library changes.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much the same.  The problem's the lack of any way of linking folders in TFS.  Multiple jobs doesn't really work for me: we'd then have a radically different local build experience from the server one.  Multiply that by 200 to get an idea of the scale of the problem.

Comment: Man, am I glad I don't use Windows for development ;-)  If you're on Vista or Windows 7, could you alleviate things using symbolic links by way of the mklink command ?

Comment: Doesn't really help, sadly.  Amazingly annoying.  This is all part of my project to get rid of TFS, but TFS is fighting back.